# How to us $.data in a loop to display correctly for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, webforms

When I click a marker on my map, I want to display data from the database associated with that marker. Currently I am doing this for the divs that I create. I am having a problem when I click on a div to open my form under it, I want to load the same data into the form, but currently the only data that will load into each for is the first one that ran through the loop.

Another words, my venue-list div might hold 3 venues for this one location, and I can click on each div and display a form under it, but if "Sally's Salon" is the first div in the list, every form will display "Sally's Salon" instead of  their own name. Here is my code:

```
 // initially detach form to be attached to each div on click
 var editForm = $('.edit-container').detach();

 function fillForm(title, priority) {
   $('.venue-input').val(title);
   $('.priority-input').val(priority);
 }

for(var i = array.length -1; i>=0; i--) {
  var prop = array[i].feature.prop

  if(prop.title) {

    // create variable to hold html
    var html = $([
      "<div class='venue-item'>",
        "  <span><strong>Venue Name</strong></span>",
        "  <span class='venue-name venue-title' data-title=" + prop.title + ">" + prop.title + "</span>",
        "<span class='venue-priority' data-priority=" + prop.prioritylevel + "><strong>Priority</strong>" + ' ' + prop.prioritylevel + "</span></div>"].join("\n"));

     // append venue item to venue list div with event handler to add form and prefill when clicked
     $(html).appendTo('.venue-list').on('click', function() {
       $(this).after(editForm);
       fillForm($('.venue-title').data('title'), $('.venue-priority').data('priority'));
     });
  }
```

any input would be helpful, I've been battling this for a couple days now, not sure if I am even attaching the html elements correctly but I mainly just want to be able to click on one of the html elements I create and then the data gets loaded into the form so it can be manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending multiple copies of your content, however there are 2 elements using the same `id` (`venue-priority` & `venue-title`) - which should be unique on a web page.

Thereafter, you use jQuery to get those elements, however as jQuery expects id's to be unique, it will just grab the first (or last, im not sure) element with that Id.

The solution is not to use duplicated id's in your markup.

Comment: ah yes, I see your point. Thanks for the response. I changed the id's to classes, since I wasn't really using the id's except here anyway. I'm guessing this isn't the right solution either though, I am still getting the same behavior, the form only fills the data from the first element created.

Comment: @relee24 Thats because `.val()` will do the same - only apply the value to the first matched element.

Comment: ok, that makes more sense then. I was thinking it was something more complex like me not understanding closures well enough ;). Could you point me in the right direction as to what I should be doing if .val isn't the right approach?

Comment: @relee24 - not easily, at least not without a [mcve] as I do not know what the structure of your html is.

Comment: I was able to figure it out finally :). Your answer helped tremendously, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a syntax error on line 6. You can view errors in a browser using developer tools in case there are others.

```
 $('#priority-input.val('priority);
```

should be

```
 $('#priority-input').val('priority');
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I typed that part in instead of copying it and missed one '. Problem still persists, but thanks for the typo catch. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to set the value to the value of the parameter, you should use

`$('#priority-input').val(priority);`

not

`$('#priority-input').val('priority');`